# How to call a function before a django app start?

Tags: django, python-3.x

In my django project i have to check if a database/table exist before starting application, i don't know how is better insert the code for check.
I try to add in views.py into login function a try except block but i was try to find an elegant and more effective solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check the check framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/checks/

Answer (score 3):

To check before the app starts then you can use the AppConfig.ready() function.  This gets called before the application starts, but after your project has started.  If you want to check before the project starts then you will have to hook into the method you use to start your project, eg within wsgi.py or even manage.py

AppConfig.ready() [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) Note that the docs specifically say

> avoid interacting with the database in your ready() implementation.

But your use case may justify doing this.

The ready function is called when you run the commands from manage.py eg 
manage.py shell / manage.py migrate / etc
It won't get called when your site is visited of course.  If you want to run a DB check in response to a visitor action then that code should go into your view

You put the ready() function in your apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db import connection

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'MyApp'
    def ready(self):
        print("i am the ready function and the database test code goes here")
        # put your test code here, eg you could read all the tables from sqlite
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master;")
            rows=cursor.fetchall()
            print (rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom django admin commands and run it by using `python manage.py your_command` right before calling `python manage.py runserver`. There are detailed examples at the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/).

One of the advantages of using commands is that testing commands are fairly easy. Django has a package for calling commands `django.core.management.call_command` which enables funtionally test your command.